# Applying my custom function to a data frame python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a dataframe with a column called Signal. I want to add a new column to that dataframe and apply a custom function i've built. I'm very new at this and I seem to be having trouble when it comes to passing values that I'm getting out of a data frame column into a function so any help as to my syntax errors or reasoningg would be greatly appreciated!

```
Signal
3.98
3.78
-6.67
-17.6
-18.05
-14.48
-12.25
-13.9
-16.89
-13.3
-13.19
-18.63
-26.36
-26.23
-22.94
-23.23
-15.7
```

This is my simple function

```
def slope_test(x):
    if x >0 and x<20:
        return 'Long'
    elif x<0 and x>-20:
        return 'Short'
    else:
        return 'Flat'
```

I keep getting this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Here is the code i've tried:

```
data['Position'] = data.apply(slope_test(data['Signal']))
```

and also:

```
data['Position'] = data['Signal'].apply(slope_test(data['Signal']))
```

Comment: So wheres the code where you use your function?

Comment: `df.Signal.apply(slope_test)` ?

Comment: edited to add. sorry about that.

Comment: the answer should work, you don't need to explicitly pass the argument to `slope_test`, given that it takes 1 argument. If there are mulitple it's a little more complicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy.select` for a vectorised solution:

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [df['Signal'].between(0, 20, inclusive=False),
              df['Signal'].between(-20, 0, inclusive=False)]

values = ['Long', 'Short']

df['Cat'] = np.select(conditions, values, 'Flat')
```

**Explanation**

You are attempting to perform operations on a series as if it were a scalar. This won't work for the reason explained in your error. In addition, your logic for `pd.Series.apply` is incorrect. This method takes a *function* as an input. Therefore, you can simply use `df['Signal'].apply(slope_test)`.

But `pd.Series.apply` is a glorified, inefficient loop. You should utilise the vectorised functionality available with NumPy arrays underlying your Pandas dataframe. In fact, this a good reason for using Pandas in the first place.

Comment: Bah, I knew it wasn't `cut` I was thinking of, I wanted to pass a default for out-of-bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Although your question is about `apply`, this will run in Python time. You could use a vectorized approach. This is the first one I thought of but I think I can improve on it:

(EDIT: No need to improve on it, I was looking for `np.select` which is covered in the answer by jpp so I'll leave it as-is for a demonstration of an alternative)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [-5, 2, 15, -10, 22, -50]})
df['category'] = pd.cut(df['a'], [-20, 0, 20], 
                        labels=['short', 'long']).replace(np.NaN, 'flat')
```

Comment: That will be faster, but unless the df is huge, who cares

Comment: @SuperStew I care

Comment: @SuperStew but, on a more serious note, you take on quite a bit of cognitive burden by using numpy/pandas so if you're going to take that downside, you should at least use it properly to get the upside. Otherwise, why are you using those libraries in the first place?

Comment: I usually use them when i have big ass data that would best be treated in a dataframe, or at least it's much easier on me if I use a dataframe. I'll vectorize where i can easily, but unless it's really killing run time, i don't sweat it further.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use [`.apply()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to the series of your dataframe and pass your custom function.

```
df.Signal.apply(slope_test)
```

Or, you can use `lambda` + `apply` (which is NOT recommended in this case) as below:

```
df.Signal.apply(lambda x: slope_test(x))
```

Output:

```
0      Long
1      Long
2     Short
3     Short
4     Short
5     Short
6     Short
7     Short
8     Short
9     Short
10    Short
11    Short
12     Flat
13     Flat
14     Flat
15     Flat
16    Short
Name: Signal, dtype: object
```

Comment: that did the trick. For my own personal knoweldge - what is happening when i use the syntax df.Signal.apply(slope_test()) that's causing it not to work?

Comment: you don't need to pass arguments to slope_test when using apply, just the name of the function

Comment: You want to pass a function to the .apply() method, not the result of a function call.

Comment: @novawaly  Consider edit, if you want to pass argument explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas.DataFrame.apply(), this work for me:

Initialize DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

d = [
    3.98, 3.78, -6.67, -17.6, -18.05, -14.48,
    -12.25, -13.9, -16.89, -13.3, -13.19, -18.63,
    -26.36, -26.23, -22.94, -23.23, -15.7]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Define the function you want to apply

```
def slope_test(x):
    if x >0 and x<20:
        return 'Long'
    elif x<0 and x>-20:
        return 'Short'
    else:
        return 'Flat'
```

Apply the function to the right column of your DataFrame

```
df[0].apply(slope_test)
>> 0      Long
1      Long
2     Short
3     Short
4     Short
5     Short
6     Short
7     Short
8     Short
9     Short
10    Short
11    Short
12     Flat
13     Flat
14     Flat
15     Flat
16    Short
Name: 0, dtype: object
```